# Dynamically setting a value to a Sass variable and a TS variable in Angular

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I am developing an Angular 5 project and I have come across a situation where I need an array of values for both my TS and SCSS files for a component. For eg. I need to have an array of colour values. Currently I am putting the same values in both the TS and SCSS files like this

`const colours = ['#7cb5ec','#434348','#90ed7d',...];`

`$colors: #7cb5ec #434348 #90ed7d ...;`

Since there can be a lot of colour values and the values (and their order) needs to be the same in both places, I was wondering if I could keep the values in one place, preferable in a service, and use them in both the places.

**Note:** I am running an angular-cli project and I don't want to `eject` that to a webpack project. Also I do realise that SCSS is processed to CSS. I want the values to be populated and consumed when the SCSS is getting processed.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10

Comment: Its a nice resource but it specifically talks about a Webpack project. As I mentioned before, I would like to stick to angular-cli. Moreover it talks about loaders which afaik possible only in a webpack config. If the technique mentioned there is somehow possible using angular-cli itself, it would be golden!!

Comment: You may send a feature request to angular-cli team. Or build it yourself.